# passing parameter in jquery auto complete

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to implement auto complete in my rails application. I'm trying to pass ruby parameter via source of the jquery. Here is what I'm trying to do.

```
$( "#text" ).autocomplete({
appendTo: "#searchwrapper1",
source:  h_url+"product_details/menu_search_auto/" + <%= "'#{params[:deptid]}'" %> ,
open:function() {
        $(".ui-autocomplete").mCustomScrollbar1({
            set_width : false,
            set_height : false, 
            horizontalScroll : false, 
            scrollInertia : 550, 
            scrollEasing : "easeOutCirc", 
            mouseWheel : "auto", 
            autoDraggerLength : true, 
            scrollButtons : {
                enable : false, 
                scrollType : "continuous", 
                scrollSpeed : 20, 
                scrollAmount : 40 
            }, 
        }
```

Here is my route.rb file

```
match "/product_details/menu_search_auto/:deptid"=>'product_details#menu_search_auto'
```

and controller part is:

```
def menu_search_auto
    list=[]
    if(params[:deptid].to_s == 'all')
      b1=test4.where("name LIKE ?","#{params[:term]}%")
    else
      case params[:deptid].to_i
      when 1
        b1=test1.where("name LIKE ?","#{params[:term]}%")
      when 2
        b1=test2.where("name LIKE ?","#{params[:term]}%")
      when 3
        b1=test3.where("name LIKE ?","#{params[:term]}%")
      else
      end
    end

    b1.each do |b1|
      list << {"label"=>b1.name, "value"=>b1.name, "id"=>b1.id}
    end 

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json{render :json=>list.to_json, :layout=>false}
    end
  end
```

But neither I'm able to pass the parameter nor I'm getting any error.

Please suggest me where I'm going wrong??

Comment: maybe you append some code (e.g. the product_details_controller#menu_search_auto and the routing for this action in your config/routes.rb ) so we can see something more.  
Another tip: add the server log (request and response) so we can see what is being passed and why.

Comment: @erndenson I've edited.

Comment: controller and routes seem to be ok.  
i think the parameter is not passed because there's a problem with the embedded ruby (erb) in your js.  
Maybe it's better to change single and double quotes there and check if the parameter is just not set.  
Can you <%= puts SOME PARAMETER %> somewhere in your js to see if its interpreted. Does the js have the .erb extension?

Comment: sorry, wanted to make a line break but entered the comment before finishing it

Comment: @erndenson Yeah my file .js.erb extension. I added <%= puts "search all" %> before the source line.but didn't get any response.

Comment: how is the js-file (your first code example) included into the html / haml-template? the problem seems to be, that your javascript does not even get executed. Is this possible?

Comment: @erndenson yeah. I've defined that search bar in rails layout file. I tried to add the js file which contains autocomlpete function in homepage.js where all js functions are defined. but when I did this its not loading the home page also.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the code you obtain at your post is in a view with js(.coffee) extension.

The way you wrote it, the "<%=" stuff are recognized as js code.

Try the following.

In your controller:

```
def an_action
  @foo = "something"
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end 
end
```

and in your view:

```
source:  h_url+"product_details/menu_search_auto/<%= j("#{@foo}") %>"
```

Comment: I'm trying to pass parameter "department_id" to the controller action called "menu_search_auto". I don't want to acces variables from the controller.

Comment: How do you get the value of the department_id that you want to pass to your controller? If you know the value, then add it as a query parameter to the url: `'foo/bar?department_id=' + depid`

Comment: may I know what is foo/bar? please explain since I'm newbie

Comment: An example of a url. For your case: `source:  h_url+"product_details/menu_search_auto?department_id=" + depid`

Comment: I added as you told. but didn't find any difference. I think its not recognizing that .js.erb file

Answer (score 0):

I've defined that search bar in rails layout file. I added the js file which contains autocomlpete function in homepage.js where all js functions are defined.Also I defined autocomplete function inside document.ready(function(). I passed the parameter as mentioned below

```
source: h_url+"product_details/menu_search_auto/" + deptid1,
```